# Docker overlay network. 3rd host never connects

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

So i need some help

Creating  a  swarm:
`docker swarm init --advertise-addr 10.98.21.1`

Creating network
`docker network create -d overlay --attachable --subnet=10.0.10.0/29 overnet`

Adding node2
`docker swarm join --token <token> --advertise-addr 10.98.21.2 10.98.21.1:2377`
And the  same for node3
`docker swarm join --token <token> --advertise-addr 10.98.21.2 10.98.21.1:2377`

So now  we are staring  our containers

HOST1
`ducker run -it --name UNIQNAME1 --network overnet 'somecontainer' /bin/bash`
HOST2
`ducker run -it --name UNIQNAME2 --network overnet 'somecontainer' /bin/bash`
HOST3
`ducker run -it --name UNIQNAME3 --network overnet 'somecontainer' /bin/bash`

and always the  3rd machine(not host) that's attaching to  overlay network in  my  case overnet is  getting

`docker: Error response from daemon: attaching to  network failed, make sure your network  options are correct and check manager logs: context deadline exceeded`

And it's always  the  3rd machine that is connecting to  the  network, no  mather if its HOST1 or HOST2 or HOST3

Ports:
TCP port 2377 for cluster management communications
TCP and UDP port 7946 for communication among nodes
UDP port 4789 for overlay network traffic
All open

availability is  in  Active

i had this issue the first time  at docker 18.09. Im now on  20.10.03 and still the same. help :)